# UIPickerView not loading from viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, viewdidappear

I have a UIPickerview, which I was initially setting from viewDidLoad. It was working perfectly fine.

But I want it to refresh it everytime I come back from another view, so I put in viewDidAppear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    NSLog(@"View will appear");
    [self loadthepicker];

}


-(void) loadthepicker
{

    pickerLoaderArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [pickerLoaderArray addObject:@"one"];
    [pickerLoaderArray addObject:@"two"];
    [pickerLoaderArray addObject:@"thee"];
    [pickerLoaderArray addObject:@"four"];

    [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

}



-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(NSInteger)component
{

    return 1;

}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return [pickerLoaderArray count];

}



-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)picker titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    return [pickerLoaderArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Okay, I think I might have got the answer:

[pickerView reloadAllComponents];

I added this to loadthepicker function and it's working fine now.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes , that's the correct way of doing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must call

```
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

Answer (score 0):

UIPickerview delegates methods called before viewDidApear method so you have to called delegates method of uipikerview explicit.

```
-(void) loadthepicker
{

pickerLoaderArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[pickerLoaderArray addObject:@"one"];
[pickerLoaderArray addObject:@"two"];
[pickerLoaderArray addObject:@"thee"];
[pickerLoaderArray addObject:@"four"];

[self.pickerview selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
[self.pickerview reloadAllComponents];
}
```